# PHP cannot access public variable inside of switch

Tags: php

OK, so I have a class called user. In that class, I have a couple of public variables like "key" (Used for encryption). Also a couple of functions but the only relevant one is get_all(). This function gets all data from a database and stores it in these public variables (So I can access them from another class).

```
class User
{

    public $uuid = "";
    public $key = "";

    public function get_all()
    {
        $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'BOTNET');

        $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE uuid=?");

        $sql->bind_param('s', $this->uuid);

        if ($sql->execute())
        {
            if ($all_info = $sql->get_result()) // This fails
            {
                while ($row = $all_info->fetch_assoc())
                {   
                    $this->key = $row["_Key"];
                    ...
                }

            }

            error_log("ERROR"); // Gets logged
            error_log(mysqli_error($db)); // This doesnt log anything

        }
}
```

Now to the problem: I have a second file lets say index.php in there I access the user class in the following way:

```
$user = new User();
$user->set_uuid(some_uuid);
$user->get_all(); (Set all public variables)
$key = $user->key; (Now I should have a string with the users key, but no: $key is just empty)
```

This exact code works in different classes, and when it's outside of the switch

The switch:

```
switch ($_POST["action"])
{
    case 1:
        $user = new User();
        $user->set_uuid(some_uuid);
        $user->get_all(); (Set all public variables)
        $key = $user->key; (Now I should have a string with the users key)
        break;
    ...
  }
```

Comment: sry forgot to add the $this (I manually wrote the code her and simply forgot to add it)

Comment: What is the value of `$_POST["action"]`

Comment: its 1 I tested it with error_log()

Comment: in the switch statement, you have `$User->key`, in upper-case, but you defined `$user` in lower key. Not sure if it's a typo on SO or in the original code.

Comment: ok I will try it out

Comment: @Dharman It's good to refer the user to that question, but it's hardly a duplicate. Otherwise almost every question about using SQL from PHP would be a duplicate of that, since SQL-injection vulnerability is rampant.

Comment: @Dharman His problem is just that he mistyped a variable name, it has nothing to do with the functions he's using to perform the query.

Comment: You don't have the object $User but you do have $user

Comment: Oops, missed that. So he needs to call `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: There are probably better duplicates for the "forgot to call mysqli_query" error than the "how to prevent SQL injection" question. But questions like this aren't really much use, so we should just comment about it and close the question as "cannot reproduce".

Comment: Ok so I updated it to use bind param etc but it fails for some reason.

Comment: [How to enable MySQLi exception mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: I am not even getting any error. BTW if it helps I am using the built-in PHP web server.